# Count Number of times a nested FLWOR loop runs in XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

If you had a nested FLWOR statement like this with two 'for' statements:

```
for $x at $xPos in (1, 2, 3)
 for $y at $yPos in fn:doc("/foo")//b
return ()
```

How would you count exactly how many times the for loop ran? Assume 'fn:doc("/foo")//b' returns sequences in random length, so here is an example run:

```
$xPos  $yPos
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
3       1 <-- for loop ends here (total times ran = 6)
```

And another example run could be:

```
$xPos  $yPos
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       2
2       3
3       1
3       2
3       3
3       4 <-- for loop ends here (total times ran = 9)
```

Well hopefully, you get my point. How do I keep and update a counter variable within the nested for loop to count how many times I ran through this loop without having it reset at every iteration of the loop?

**Clarification EDIT**:
This question is just based on pure curiosity to know if this is possible in XQuery. I know that you can just simply put a let statement like so and just keep track of $xPos which is a simple matter:

```
for $x at $xPos in (1, 2, 3)
let $_ :=
 for $y at $yPos in fn:doc("/foo")//b
 return ()
return ()
```

Comment: A `for` expression is not a loop. Does Marklogic XQuery support the `count` clause (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-count)?

Comment: I also think the claim "Assume 'fn:doc("/foo")//b' returns sequences in random length" together with the presented `$yPos` sequences doesn't make sense, the number of items returned by `fn:doc("/foo")//b` would be the same for each item processed by the outer `for` expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MarkLogic you can use [xdmp:set](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set) to break out of the strict FLWOR paradigm.

```
let $count := 0
for $x at $xPos in (1, 2, 3)
for $y at $yPos in ("a", "b", "c")
let $set := xdmp:set($count, $count + 1)
return concat($count, ": ", $x, " ", $y)
```

Produces:

```
1: 1 a
2: 1 b
3: 1 c
4: 2 a
5: 2 b
6: 2 c
7: 3 a
8: 3 b
9: 3 c
```

Answer (score 2):

XQuery 3 has a `count` clause (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-count):

```
for $x in (1 to 3)
for $y in //b
count $c
return ``[count `{$c}`: y: `{$y}`]``
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKvF for the input

```
<doc>
    <b>a</b>
    <b>b</b>
    <b>c</b>
</doc>
```

returns the result

```
count 1: y: a
count 2: y: b
count 3: y: c
count 4: y: a
count 5: y: b
count 6: y: c
count 7: y: a
count 8: y: b
count 9: y: c
```

However, if I interpret https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/langoverview#id_11626 correctly, then Marklogic doesn't support the `count` clause.

Answer (score 0):

How about just counting afterwards:

```
for $x at $xPos in (1, 2, 3)
let $c :=
 for $y at $yPos in fn:doc("/foo")//b
 return 1
return count($c)
```

HTH!